Spherical Wave Equation With a Source and Time-dependent Velocity
In my research I am studying a type of soliton known as Q-balls. The standard equation of motion obtained for the spatial part of a Q-ball is (where $f = f(r)$) $$\frac{d^2f}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r} \frac{df}{dr} + \omega^2f = \nabla^2 f+ \omega ^2 f= \frac{dU}{df},$$ where $U(f)$ is a potential that is a polynomial in $f$. This is found for a flat geometry, with no time dependence on the function $f$. In my situation, I need to introduce both curved geometry as well as time dependence on $f$, obtaining the equation $$\frac{1}{a(t)^2} \nabla^2f - \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial t^2} - 3 \frac{\dot a}{a} \frac {\partial f}{\partial t}+ \omega^2 f = \frac{dU}{df}$$ where the Laplacian takes the form $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac 2 r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, $U$ is again a polynomial in $f$, and $a(t)$ is a purely time dependent function that governs the expansion of spacetime, and we assume that $\dot a = \text{const}$ (therefore $a = \alpha t +\beta$). I have noticed that this equation looks an awfully lot like a spherical wave equation with a source, and a time dependent velocity. The question is: are there any known solutions of such an equation, or at the very least what methods could be used to solve it? Even non-exact methods or numerical approaches would be of interest. I have thought that using a form of perturbation theory could work, neglecting the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ term, and treating it as a small perturbation. This could work if the equation obtained from neglecting this term has an exact solution.

This is the telegraphers equation in radial coordinates with non-constant coefficients and a source. Perhaps this will help you find what you are looking for.

@MatthewCassell Thanks for that! Are you aware of any solution methods for such an equation (I'm not trained in solving complex PDEs like this)?

Sorry, I just read that $U$ is polynomial in $f$, so what I stated above is not quite correct. You would probably call the problem a nonlinear Telegraphers equation in radial coordinates with non-constant coefficients. The solution will depend on the domain which hasn't been provided, though the nonlinearity may make it difficult to find exact solutions irrespective of the domain. If you were going to solve this numerically I would suggest using a spectral method; a package like the Dedalus project could do it.
